# how do i make an api call in python (GAE)?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, recaptcha

I have made a simple web form in Google app engine where I have added a recaptcha component.
The component is showing up on my web page. But i have no idea how to make the api call.
my code is;

```
def post(self):

    challenge = self.request.get('recaptcha_challenge_field')
    response  = self.request.get('recaptcha_response_field')
    remoteip  = os.environ['REMOTE_ADDR']
    private_key = 'xxx'

    cResponse = self.request.submit(http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/verify?privatekey="private_key"&remoteip="remoteip"&challenge="challenge"&response="response")

    if cResponse.is_valid:
        # response was valid
        # other stuff goes here
        pass
    else:
        error = cResponse.error_code
```

its pretty clear that my api call is completely wrong but i have no idea how to make it.
The examples i have seen use the plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the URL Fetch API [documented here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/overview), the first example in the linked page should be suitable for your needs.
Notice that url fetches have a quota and are billable.

Comment: thanks. is there no free option?
i will try to add this in my code now and update on the result.

Comment: Yes, you can use it for free under the quota limits: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#UrlFetch